# MVC5 Validate- To date greater than from date

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having two datepickers fields on my form, and i would like to validate that the to date is greater than from date.

Is there any validation attribute in MVC5 which I can use to achieve this?

I would also like this to work on client side, can some body please help in enabling client side validation in MVC?

Many Thanks

Edit: Created the custom attribute, but client side validation not working.

```
public class ValidateToDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {

        public string errorMessageKey { get; private set; }

        public ValidateToDateAttribute(string errorMessageKey)
        {
            this.errorMessageKey = errorMessageKey;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var viewModel = (TransactionViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
                if (viewModel.ToDate.CompareTo(viewModel.FromDate) < 0)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(new ResourceManager(typeof(ValidationErrorMessages)).GetString(errorMessageKey));
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var modelClientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ValidationType = "validatetodate",
                ErrorMessage = new ResourceManager(typeof(ValidationErrorMessages)).GetString(errorMessageKey)
            };

            yield return modelClientValidationRule;
        }
    }
}
```

Bundle.Config

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryvalidation").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

View Model

```
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(DisplayLabelText), Name = "FromDate")]       
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(DisplayLabelText), Name = "ToDate")]
    [ValidateToDate("ToDateMustBeGreater")]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
```

in View:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 margin-top-10">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromDate, new { @class = "col-sm-3 form-group control-label" })
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, "{0:MMM dd yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker", disabled = "disabled" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ToDate, new { @class = "col-sm-3 form-group control-label" })
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, "{0:MMM dd yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker", disabled = "disabled" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ToDate)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="apply-filter-button">Apply Filter</button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: We're not here to provide you with complete tutorials or do all the work/research for you.  We're primarily here to help you with a piece of code you've written or to answer a concise question.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why are you using the MVC3 and MVC4 tags when you're asking about MVC5?  Tag-spamming is not allowed here.

Comment: No intention of tag spamming, i just thought the solution for mvc3 and mvc4 might still be valid for MVC5.

Comment: _"i just thought the solution for mvc3 and mvc4 might still be valid for MVC5"_  ~ Yes, that's pretty much the definition of tag-spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was missing the unobtrusive java script code:
please see the below, it might be helpful for some one.

```
public class ValidateToDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{       
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ValidateToDateAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="errorMessageKey">The error message key.</param>
    public ValidateToDateAttribute(string errorMessageKey, string otherProperty)
    {
        this.ErrorMessageKey = errorMessageKey;
        this.FromDate = otherProperty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets from date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// From date.
    /// </value>
    public string FromDate { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the error message key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The error message key.
    /// </value>
    public string ErrorMessageKey { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When implemented in a class, returns client validation rules for that class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="metadata">The model metadata.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The controller context.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The client validation rules for this validator.
    /// </returns>
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var modelClientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "validatetodate",
            ErrorMessage = new ResourceManager(typeof(ValidationErrorMessages)).GetString(this.ErrorMessageKey),               
        };

        modelClientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("other", this.FromDate);
        yield return modelClientValidationRule;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the specified value with respect to the current validation attribute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to validate.</param>
    /// <param name="validationContext">The context information about the validation operation.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An instance of the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult" /> class.
    /// </returns>
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var viewModel = (TransactionViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            if (viewModel.ToDate.CompareTo(viewModel.FromDate) < 0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(new ResourceManager(typeof(ValidationErrorMessages)).GetString(this.ErrorMessageKey));
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.addMethod('greaterThan', function (value, element, params) {        
    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
        //return new Date(value) > new Date($("input[name='FromDate']").val());            
        return Date.parse(value) > Date.parse($(params).val());
    }       
    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(fromDate)) || (parseFloat(value) > parseFloat($("input[name='FromDate']").val()));
}, '');

// and an unobtrusive adapter
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('validatetodate', ["other"], function (options) {       
    options.rules['greaterThan'] = "#" + options.params.other;
    options.messages['greaterThan'] = options.message;
});
```